# Assign Public IP address to Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Can someone let me know if its possible to attach an existing public ip address to a Load Balancer? At the moment, we have a public address assigned to one of our devices by Azure. We would like to disassociate the address from the device and use the same on our Load balancer. Is that possible?

Regards

Carlton

Comment: we can via azure portal to do it, I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We would like to disassociate the address from the device and use the
>   same on our Load balancer. Is that possible?

Yes, it is possible, before disassociate the public IP address, we should set this public IP address to **static**, in this way, the IP address will not change to other address.

After that, we can associate this public IP address to Azure load balancer.

---

**Update:**

We can associate this IP address to LB via Azure portal, like this:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, for example with an arm template, this is the part that assigns ip address:

```
 "frontendIPConfigurations": [
      {
           "name": "elb-FE",
            "properties": {
                "publicIPAddress": {
                      "id": "IP_ADDRESS_ID_GOES_HERE"
                }
           }
      }
]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Is it possible from the portal?

Comment: yeah, just press + on the frontendipconfigurations

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't realize it was that straight forward.

Comment: Hi Jason, I just tried your suggestion but it didn't work... The option to associate is greyed out .. I can only dissociate.

Comment: Hi Jason, the solution using the portal doesn't appear to work